# Using TCPClient with RAW FTP to retrieve file

Tags: c#, ftp, tcpclient

I get the following message back when trying to retrieve a file using TCPClient and RAW FTP:

> 425 Failed to establish connection.

I connect using :

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("ServerName", 21))
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
```

Then I login to the server fine using `USER ****` and `PASS ***`. I manage to change to the correct directory using `CWD /**/**`, as mentioned this all works fine and i get the expected response messages.

However when the following code executes the message mentioned above is all i receive.

```
lineToSend = "PASV";
Program.logger.Add("Sending to server: " + lineToSend, 1);
writer.WriteLine(lineToSend);
while (!stream.DataAvailable)
{
    Program.logger.Add(stream.DataAvailable.ToString(), 1);
    Program.logger.Persist();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

}
lineWeRead = reader.ReadLine();
Program.logger.Add("Received from server: " + lineWeRead, 1);
Program.logger.Persist();

lineToSend = "RETR file.txt";
Program.logger.Add("Sending to server: " + lineToSend, 1);
writer.WriteLine(lineToSend);
while (!stream.DataAvailable)
{
    Program.logger.Add(stream.DataAvailable.ToString(), 1);
    Program.logger.Persist();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

Program.logger.Add("Loop Exited: " + stream.DataAvailable.ToString(), 1);
Program.logger.Persist();
lineWeRead = reader.ReadLine();
Program.logger.Add("Received from server: " + lineWeRead, 1);
Program.logger.Persist();
```

I am fairly new to C#.NET and have been asked specifically to use this method of connecting and not the httpWebRequest.

The file I am trying to receive is a text file containing only "Get this message" but will be bigger when used. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you use `FtpWebRequest`?  Unless this is homework, tell whoever asked you that there's no point in reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read up on the FTP protocol.  There is not one connection, but *two* involved.  I don't see a data connection anywhere in your code, which is probably where the 425 is coming from.

I agree with the comment -- unless this is a homework-style question, please don't reinvent the wheel here.  FTP stinks and this problem has been solved.

Comment: +1 If you really plan to use TcpClient, you need an extra Socket or TcpListener object for FTP active mode, or another TcpClient or Socket object for FTP passive mode.